# How do I install XAMPP for PHP?? on a Mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I tried downloading xampp and running it but had issues in opening it.

When opening the package, I get a message- cannot open because developer cannot be identified.

I tried going on privacy and security and going to block apps to approve, but the error persists.

Is there a way to bypass this?

TY.

Answer (score -1):

Did you go to the General tab under Security & Privacy? That's where the setting is. At the bottom of the panel, it will show the package that was recently blocked (in your case, XAMPP). Next to it there's a button that says "Open Anyway." Clicking that solved the problem for me - the warning came up again, but this time there was a button that said "Open" above "Eject Disk."

Btw, if you happen to be setting up a dev environment for WordPress, I would recommend [DevKinsta](https://kinsta.com/devkinsta/)! It's created by a managed hosting provider, but it's free and it's super convenient for developing locally for WP on Mac.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use of `AMPPS` application . It's better than `XAMPP` for MacOS !

I had this problem about 1 years ago and installed `AMPPS`